# Telegraf: can't use extra

Tags: html, node.js, bots, telegram, telegraf

Simple usage works fine:

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');
const bot = new Telegraf(tgBotToken);
bot.telegram.sendMessage(tgChatId, "My message");
```

But if I want to use HTML in my message, I need to require telegraf/extra

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');
const tgExtra = require('telegraf/extra');
```

But I get an error:

```
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './extra' is not defined by "exports" in C:\MyProject\node_modules\telegraf\package.json
```

Telegraf was installed via `npm install telegraf`. Running `npm install telegraf/extra` leads to trying to install non-existing package.

Is there any trick of installing something extra for... extra?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Telegraf V4 . As there [changelog](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/releases/tag/v4.0.0) says , `Extra` has been entirely removed in V4 .

> Extra is removed entirely, see [#1076](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/1076).
>
> You can now just specify any options directly, without having to create an `Extra` instance before

Answer (score 1):

In Telegraf V4, the Extra now is inside if the 'telegraf'.

Example:

```
const { Telegraf, Markup } = require('telegraf');

const bot = new Telegraf(tgBotToken);
bot.on('message', async ctx => {
    ctx.replyWithHTML(tgChatId, "My message", Markup.button.url('Button Name', 'https://you.url'));
})
```